# What should be the minimum value of the function $f(x)= \frac{1}{\sin(x)}$, where $0 \leq x < 1$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$$  where $$(.)$$ represents the fractional part of function.
I have computed for the maximum value and that tends to infinity but I cannot find the lower bound of the range of the function. A little guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Take derivative, set equal to 0. My guess is sqrt(2). Woops, @PC1 is correct. I misthought that as minimum absolute value

Comment: It would obviously be $-\infty$

Comment: $\sin'(x)$ doesn't change sign and doesn't become zero over the domain $0<x<1$. Also, $\frac1x$ is strictly decreasing so the minimum and maximum must happen either at $x=0$ or $x=1$.

Comment: I graphed it on desmos and it gave me the range from (-infinity,+infinity) and I too computed it but I again thought {x} can only range from 0 to 1 ,so I thought it couldn't be negative.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=minimize+1%2Fsin%28x%29+where+x%3E0+and+x%3C1 says the minimum is about 1.1884 where x is 1. This actually makes sense since sin(x) increases between 0 and pi/2 so sin(x) is biggest at 1, the boundary point, which is less than pi/2

Comment: @barrycarter ,if you're talking about just x then fractional part of x should be zero and if you're talking about (x) it can never be 1, it ranges from [0,1)

Comment: @ShariqueAhmad OK, my mistake. Could you use a different symbol to mean fractional part of a value? Like `1/sin(frac(x))` or something? Using parentheses for both function calls and the frac() function is confusing. With your caveat, there is no minimum, but the function has a lower bound per my notes above

Answer (score 2):

The function does not have a minimum on $0 \leq x <1$ because it is not a closed interval.  We can only say that the infimum is $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}\frac{1}{\sin(x)} = \frac{1}{\sin(1)},$ since $\sin(\cdot)$ is an increasing function on this interval.  The fractional part of $x$ is the same as $x$.

This explanation works even if you restrict $x$ to be rational.  Given any $\epsilon>0$, I can find a rational $x<1$ for which $|1/\sin(1)-1/\sin(x)|<\epsilon$.